# background image fadeIn problem

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

I am using fadeIn effect on the body of my pages, but there is a particular page with a big background image which i have included in the body tag of that image however it does not fade in which ruins the effect. How can i achieve that? Here is my current code..

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").css("display", "none");
    $("body").fadeIn(3000);
});  

 body{
    background: #ffffff url("../images/test.jpg") no-repeat;
    z-index: -2;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977090/jquery-fade-in-background-image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to fade `<body>` -- a workaround would be to wrap everything in a container, and set an image on that.

HTML:

```
<body><div id="container">**all your site content goes here**</div></body>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#container').hide().fadeIn(3000);
});
```

**fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ztXnZ/2/

---

**edit**: Interesting, a body tag's CONTENT can be faded but it will not act on any CSS backgrounds ON the body tag. Demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/Fxvdz/

Comment: +1 same solution as I came up with, except [mine](http://jsfiddle.net/ywZqA/) had added "Star Wars"! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code this way

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").css("display", "none");
    $("body").addClass("body1").fadeIn(3000);
});
```

create this CSS class

```
.body1 {
    background: #ffffff url("../images/test.jpg") no-repeat;
    z-index: -2;
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me in Chrome. Can you create a demo on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: sure will try that n let u know