# Fading background images with jQuery/css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following script ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977090/jquery-fade-in-background-image)) that loads up an image and sets it as the background. It works fine, but what would I need to change to add more than one photo so it can be a slideshow?

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.fn.smartBackgroundImage = function(url){
        var t = this;
        //create an img so the browser will download the image:
        $('<img />')
        .attr('src', url)
        .load(function(){ //attach onload to set background-image
                t.each(function(){ 
                $(this).css('backgroundImage', 'url('+url+')' );
                });
            });
        return this;
    }
    $('body').smartBackgroundImage('/static/images/temp-bg.jpg');

});
```

**Thank you!**

Comment: No offense or anything, but just think about it. It appears you know how to code in JS, so that's not the problem. Think through your problem logically in terms of what you need to happen, then think in terms of your specific situation, then in terms of the actual code. If you have a problem along the way, make *that* the question. Broader questions like are frowned upon more than narrower, researched questions.  Good luck! :)

Comment: No offense taken :) It was just that I was running late on a project. The solution seems simple: probably put in a loop that fades through the images.

Comment: been there. :) for the record, `setInterval(time)` comes in handy here. Just set an interval to change the picture on. https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setInterval

Comment: I managed to do it with jQuery Cycle. Just made the .slideshow box's position absolute. Wow, so easy hehe.

Comment: Make it a false background.  For instance, a div containing a jQuery banner, and then place the elements of your site on top of it.  Check out how it's done here http://www.globalholdings.com   The only way I can think to do it using background-image css is if you faded it out, replaced the url, then faded it back in, but then that fade out would be applied to all the object within it.

Answer (score 0):

incorporate your images in html with `<li>` tags, and format them with jquery. so its easier to change them later on.