# Can't ga a fade in a hover in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to change the page background image of a page based on the mouse-over behavior of a visitor.

What’s the purpose?
I would like to have a full screen photo with Supersized Jquery in the background.
When a visitor goes over a button, I want the page to show another background image. I would like this background image to fade in.

The hover effect is located in a list. The image that need to fade is located in the body background. I already made the background change when I hover the list items. But i can't get the fade in.

The code I have at the moment:

```
$(document).ready(function()
 {
    var colorOrig=$("body").css('background-image');

$(".first").hover(
function() {
    $("body").css('background-image', 'url(images/foto-de-skater.jpg)');
}, function() {
    $("body").css('background-image', colorOrig);
});

$(".second").hover(
function() {
    $("body").css('background-image', 'url(images/girls.jpg)');

}, function() {
    $("body").css('background-image', colorOrig);
});

$(".third").hover(
function() {
    $("body").css('background-image', 'url(images/inter0507fumoniCurvaSudRoma1973.jpg)');
}, function() {
    $("body").css('background-image', colorOrig);
});});
```

The images I use are random chosen images.

Comment: Checkout [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977090/jquery-fade-in-background-image) on stackoverflow. Theck the article in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are refering to image opacity when a black background is behind the image. Am I right?

If so, then make a div element right after the declaration of body, and set the div you created to have the same size as body. Set body to have black background.
Then when you hover over .first, .second or .third it will change the image of the div instead of body.  Example:

```
$(document).ready(function()
 {
    var colorOrig= $("#yourDiv").css('background-image');
    var imgOpacity = 0.5;

$(".first").hover(
function() {
    $("#yourDiv").css({ 'background-image': 'url(images/foto-de-skater.jpg)', opacity:imgOpacity });
}, function() {
    $("#yourDiv").css({ 'background-image': colorOrig, opacity:imgOpacity });
});

$(".second").hover(
function() {
   $("#yourDiv").css({ 'background-image': 'url(images/girls.jpg)', opacity:imgOpacity });

}, function() {
    $("#yourDiv").css({ 'background-image': colorOrig, opacity:imgOpacity });
});

$(".third").hover(
function() {
    $("#yourDiv").css({ 'background-image': 'url(images/inter0507fumoniCurvaSudRoma1973.jpg)', opacity:imgOpacity });
}, function() {
    $("#yourDiv").css({ 'background-image': colorOrig, opacity:imgOpacity });
});});
```

EDIT:

```
$(document).ready(function()
 {
    function fadeImage (img) {
        $("body").stop(true).animate ({ opacity: 0 }, 'fast', function () {
            $(this).css ('background-image', img).animate ({ opacity: 1 }, 'fast');
        });
    }
    var colorOrig=$("body").css('background-image');

$(".first").hover(
function() {
    fadeImage ('url(images/foto-de-skater.jpg)');
}, function() {
    fadeImage (colorOrig);
});

$(".second").hover(
function() {
    fadeImage ('url(images/girls.jpg)');

}, function() {
    fadeImage (colorOrig);
});

$(".third").hover(
function() {
    fadeImage ('url(images/inter0507fumoniCurvaSudRoma1973.jpg)');
}, function() {
    fadeImage (colorOrig);
});});
```

Latest fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/7KWjz/21/
Full screen: http://jsfiddle.net/7KWjz/21/embedded/result/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
Nevertheless, I wasn’t refering to the opacity.
What I try to accomplish is to change the background image based on the mouse-over behavior of a visitor. 
So I want to start with a Supersized image with for instance 3 buttons.
When a user goes over button 1, I would like the background image change to another image. 
Then when a user goes with the mouse over button 2, another background image needs to appear.
And so on.
All background images should have a fade in effect.

Thanks already for the help. Highly appreciated.

Comment: Also if you are going to use multiple images, i strongly suggest you pre-load them so that when you click the button it shows instantly, not after the image is loaded. This can be achieved by making a hidden div with the images. This will force the browser to load them, and when you click .second it will fade out the current image, and replace it by the loaded one. Hope I did not confuse you thanks to my bad english ;)

Comment: At line 3 I get a syntax error. I don´t know if you tested I yourself. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: There should have not been var img in function fadeImage (. It is corrected now.

Comment: The buttons I use for the hover are fading. The images only jump to the other picture when the fade effect is finished. I don't know if you have got other suggestions? Again thanks for helping me.