# Fade background image with fadeIn()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the background image, which I built a `ChangeBg` function for, to be faded.

Why is this not working? What am I doing wrong?

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.4.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
    function changeBg (color) {
        document.getElementById("wrapper").style.background="url(Images/"+color+".jpg) no-  repeat";
        $("changeBg").fadeIn("slow"); }
</script>
```

Comment: Such background transparency is not possible.

Comment: similar question answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977090/jquery-fade-in-background-image

Comment: I recomend you use only one API to traverse the DOM of the html (In this case, jquery). Instead of doing "document.getelementbyId", use $('#wrapper'). Also, what is $('changeBg') element?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are missing a `#`:

```
 $("#changeBg").fadeIn("slow");
```

if changeBg is an ID of a html element.

```
document.getElementById // <-- knows it's an ID
$() // <- can select classes, tags, :first's, :contain's, etc, etc
```

So jQuery using the hashtag, #, to specify an ID.

Answer (score 0):

A few things at a glance:

Is the `url` path of the image relative to the page? In other words, should `url(Images` be `url(/Images`?

I'm assuming that you don't actually have spaces in `no-  repeat` in your code? I'd assume that browsers wouldn't automatically clean that up for you.

Lastly (but perhaps most importantly), you have to fix your selector: `$("changeBg")` should probably be `$("#changeBg")` if `changeBg` is the element id attribute.

Answer (score 0):

What is `changebg` here ?
Did you not mean `$('#wrapper').fadeIn();` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use either jquery or javascript. don't mixed up

```
function changeBg (color) {
        $("#wrapper").css("background","url(Images/"+color+".jpg) no-repeat");
        $("#wrapper").fadeIn("slow"); 
}
```

Comment: Hi Arif,I have tried it your way,I changed the $("#changeBg").fadein("slow"); to $("#wrapper").fadein("slow"); because the ChangeBg is my function and warpper is my element,but it still don't work.

Comment: in which event did you call the function?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of fading in an element with a background-image: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/XeKLw/

HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width  : 300px;
    height : 300px;
    background : url(...) center center;
    display : none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', function () {
    $('div').fadeToggle();
});
```

Note: `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and replaces `.bind()` in this situation.