# jQuery to select background on page load complete and fadeIn

Tags: jquery, html

```
<body id="bg" style="background-attachment: fixed; background-image: url('img/c859bg.png');">
```

When the page loads, the below script should fadeIn the background image above onLoad complete. But it rather fades in the whole document. How would I just select the background image to fadeIn?

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#bg1").fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery - Fade In Background image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977090/jquery-fade-in-background-image)

Comment: @JamesHill Not a duplicate - that question relates to preloading of background images but not animating them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the entire HTML document resides within the `body` tag, it's not possible to fade it in without affecting the whole document. Instead you should [animate the background opacity](http://www.mightymeta.co.uk/307/animating-opacity-of-background-image-in-jquery-without-affecting-child-elements/) of the `body` tag. Hope that helps.

Comment: No probs. If it answered your question please tick it :)