# body background-image fade in

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to replicate the fade in the background image of this [site](http://movies.io). How would I go about doing so with jQuery?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery - Fade In Background image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977090/jquery-fade-in-background-image) and just about every question in the "related" pane on the right side.

Answer (score 3):

Use an image as a background image. i.e., `<img />` tag. Then use jQuery's `.animate()` function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img.bg').animate({
        opacity: 1;
    }, 1000);
});
```

CSS:

```
.bg {opacity: 0; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
```

HTML:

```
<img src="bgimage.png" class="bg" />
```

Comment: Minor correction `Start with opacity 1 and then make it zero as it is fade in.` `:)`

Comment: No right? He want's it to fade in. So, in that case, opacity must be 0 and should gradually become 1 right?

Comment: `:)` you can see demo below, have a nice one!

Answer (score 1):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/9HTkV/ (and coz I like hulk) :P

Start with `opacity 1` and then make it zero as it is fade in.

This should help `:)`

**code**

```
        $('.box2').animate({
            opacity: 0
        });

​
```

**CSS** in start you want Opacity to be 1 and then make it 0.

```
.box2 {
    height: 500px;
    width: 700px;
    background: #000000;
    opacity: 1;
}
```